# Docker-compose does not work in docker-machine

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I have a cookiecutter-django application with docker that works fine if I run it locally with `docker compose -f local.yml up`. Now I am trying to deploy it so first I created a docker-machine in my computer (using macOS Catalina) and activated it.

Now, inside the docker-machine, the `docker-compose build` works fine, but when I run it, the application crashes.

Any idea what can be happening? I have been trying to solve this for almost a week now...

This are my logs when I do `docker-compose up` in the docker-machine:

```
Creating network "innovacion_innsai_default" with the default driver
Creating innovacion_innsai_postgres_1 ... done
Creating innovacion_innsai_django_1   ... done
Creating innovacion_innsai_node_1     ... done
Attaching to innovacion_innsai_postgres_1, innovacion_innsai_django_1, innovacion_innsai_node_1
postgres_1  | 2020-03-16 08:41:12.472 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2020-03-16 08:41:12.472 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_1  | 2020-03-16 08:41:12.473 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_1  | 2020-03-16 08:41:12.494 UTC [21] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-03-16 08:31:09 UTC
postgres_1  | 2020-03-16 08:41:12.511 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
django_1    | PostgreSQL is available
django_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
django_1    |     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django_1    | psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "innovation_sector" does not exist
django_1    | LINE 1: ...n_sector"."id", "innovation_sector"."sector" FROM "innovatio...
django_1    |                                                              ^
django_1    | 
django_1    | 
django_1    | The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
django_1    | 
django_1    | Traceback (most recent call last):
django_1    |   File "manage.py", line 30, in <module>
django_1    |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
django_1    |     utility.execute()
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
django_1    |     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
django_1    |     self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in execute
django_1    |     self.check()
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
django_1    |     include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 65, in _run_checks
django_1    |     issues.extend(super()._run_checks(**kwargs))
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
django_1    |     return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
django_1    |     new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
django_1    |     all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
django_1    |     url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
django_1    |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 584, in url_patterns
django_1    |     patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
django_1    |     res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 577, in urlconf_module
django_1    |     return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
django_1    |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
django_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
django_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
django_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
django_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
django_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
django_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
django_1    |   File "/app/config/urls.py", line 18, in <module>
django_1    |     path("", include("innovacion_innsai.innovation.urls", namespace="innovation")),
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
django_1    |     urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
django_1    |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
django_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
django_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
django_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
django_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
django_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
django_1    |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
django_1    |   File "/app/innovacion_innsai/innovation/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
django_1    |     from innovacion_innsai.innovation import views
django_1    |   File "/app/innovacion_innsai/innovation/views.py", line 9, in <module>
django_1    |     from .analytics import alimentacion_cases, agro_cases, turismo_cases, movilidad_cases
django_1    |   File "/app/innovacion_innsai/innovation/analytics.py", line 17, in <module>
django_1    |     for case in Case.objects.filter(sector__sector=sectors[0]):
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 308, in __getitem__
django_1    |     qs._fetch_all()
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1242, in _fetch_all
django_1    |     self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 55, in __iter__
django_1    |     results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1133, in execute_sql
django_1    |     cursor.execute(sql, params)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
django_1    |     return super().execute(sql, params)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
django_1    |     return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
django_1    |     return executor(sql, params, many, context)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
django_1    |     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
django_1    |     raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
django_1    |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
django_1    |     return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django_1    | django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "innovation_sector" does not exist
django_1    | LINE 1: ...n_sector"."id", "innovation_sector"."sector" FROM "innovatio...
django_1    |                                                              ^
django_1    | 
innovacion_innsai_django_1 exited with code 1
node_1      | 
node_1      | > innovacion_innsai@1.1.0 dev /app
node_1      | > gulp
node_1      | 
node_1      | [08:41:22] Using gulpfile /app/gulpfile.js
node_1      | [08:41:22] Starting 'default'...
node_1      | [08:41:22] Starting 'styles'...
node_1      | [08:41:22] Starting 'scripts'...
node_1      | [08:41:22] Starting 'imgCompression'...
node_1      | [08:41:22] gulp-imagemin: Minified 0 images
```

This is my local.yml:

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  local_postgres_data: {}
  local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  django:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: innovacion_innsai_local_django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: innovacion_innsai_production_postgres
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - local_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    #Estas dos siguientes lineas las he añadido yo luego
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"


  node:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/node/Dockerfile
    image: innovacion_innsai_local_node
    depends_on:
      - django
    volumes:
      - .:/app
      # http://jdlm.info/articles/2016/03/06/lessons-building-node-app-docker.html
      - /app/node_modules
    command: npm run dev
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      # Expose browsersync UI: https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-ui
      - "3001:3001"
```

And this is my .postgres file inside the .envs/local folder:

```
# PostgreSQL
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
POSTGRES_HOST=postgres
POSTGRES_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_DB=innovacion_innsai
POSTGRES_USER=debug
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=debug
```

Comment: maybe you need to apply migrations first

Comment: Hi @AndreyNelubin  , thanks for replying. If I do that I get a similar error... Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File "/app/innovacion_innsai/innovation/analytics.py", line 17, in <module>
django_1    |     for case in Case.objects.filter(sector__sector=sectors[0]):
```

It means that when django is initializing (the moment it loads the modules) it's doing DB queries on database that has no migrations applied. You need to transform whatever your code is doing on line 17 to run it lazy.